# JTable - Why cell color doesn't work

Tags: java, jtable

I have JTable with 4 columns. I want only the column of index 2(That is, 'Change' column) to be rendered according to each cell's value.
Have a look at my code

```
private DefaultTableModel tmodel;
private final int table_colID_at_compID = 0;
private final int table_colID_at_compName = 1;
private final int table_colID_at_stockPresentageGrowth = 2;
private final int table_colID_at_compNetWorth = 3;

..........more code(unimportant code)..........

    tmodel = new DefaultTableModel( new String[][] {} ,new String[]{"Comp. ID","Com. Name","Change %","Net Worth"} );

    table = new JTable(tmodel){
        public Component prepareRenderer (TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
            Component componenet = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);

            if(columnIndex == table_colID_at_stockPresentageGrowth) {
                double value = new Double(getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex).toString());
                if( value < 0 )
                    componenet.setBackground(Color.RED);
                else if( value == 0)
                    componenet.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                else
                    componenet.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

            return componenet;
        }
    };
```

- All the variable with name `table_colID_at_<something>` represent the table column ID.
- As you can see at the picture(below), the program paints 2 columns ('Change' and 'Net worth'.) (It should only paint the 'Change' column)
- I debugged the program and found that the if statements are ok.
- So I suggest that the problem is with the logic behind the operations.

Image: (imgur has errors)

> http://i64.tinypic.com/fx5n2q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every other column you have to set the colour back to white.

Comment: But I ask in the IF statement for specific column index. I only check for 'Change' column , and not the others

Comment: And that is the mistake. The Component is a shared object. If you set the color once it will remain.

Comment: Thank you a lot Christian! I just added after the big IF statement ELSE to set background to white. Though I'm not sure why it paints the next row with color.